# Arrow function import and usage in component context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

My question is what is the best approach in usage of arrow function or common function when we are importing them and use them in component class context.

I saw some examples how to make our component less overloaded with logic, and in this case were used some utils.js that contains some part of functions.

So we see something like this:

### Option 1

#### In utils.js:

```
function someFunction() {
 [some logic]
 this.setState({
  [update some state]
 })
}

export {
 someFunction,
}
```

#### In component.js:

```
import { someFunction } from './utils'

class Component extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.someFunction = someFunction.bind(this)
  }
```

In first case we use .bind(this) and function can access component context.

### Option 2

#### In utils.js:

```
const someFunction = () => {
 [some logic]
 this.setState({
  [update some state]
 })
}

export {
 someFunction,
}
```

#### In component.js:

```
import { someFunction } from './utils'

class Component extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.someFunction = someFunction
  }
```

In second option we are storing arrow function in local variable and again through it we can access Component context.

So does in this scenario arrow function have any advantages comparing to common function?
What is the best practice to import those function? 
Use arrow or simple function?

Comment: I don't think that option 2 is even possible

Answer (score 0):

It's just my opinion, but all your examples is pieces of bad practice. You can store some logic in the function, but you shouldn't make a state update in it.

It could be better, if you try to make a custom hook, and store your state and logic there.